# Syntax error in gulpfile.js

Tags: gulp

Im doing a simple app project with flask and react for the front end stuff. For the bundling and compile im trying to use gulp but i got stuck with this error.

This the error im getting when trying to run gulp:

```
gulpfile.js:9
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:193:16)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gul7
```

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var es = require('event-stream');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
​
gulp.task('transform', function () {
​
    var files = [
        'index.jsx'
    ];
​
    var tasks = files.map(function(entry){
        return browserify({entries: './static/jsx/' + entry})
        .transform('babelify', {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(err){
            console.log(err.stack);
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(source(entry))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/static/js'));
    });
​
    return es.merge.apply(null,tasks);

});
​
​
gulp.task('watch', ['transform'], function () {
    gulp.watch('./app/static/jsx/**/*.jsx', ['transform']);
});
​
​
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invisible illegal characters in some lines of your code, which prevent it from running.
https://jsfiddle.net/9mg23vxj/ - shown as a red dots by JSfiddle.
Remove them and everything should be ok.

```
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
​ <--- Here is the symbol.
gulp.task('transform', function () {
​
```